# Mac OSX Lion, Eclipse, and Applications folder

Tags: eclipse, osx-lion

I recently decided to switch to my MBP for full time dev work. I need to install Eclipse and all the tutorials I have seen always put it in the Applications folder. Does eclipse need to be installed there? I would prefer to keep programs that I get from .tar.gz in my ~/opt directory and want to make sure putting eclipse there will not cause any issues.  Is Applications just like Program Files on windows a common place to store programs but not a required one.

I appreciate the feedback.

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been running on my MBP for a while.  I have STS (spring's eclipse based IDE) in ~/apps/sts so I think it's safe to say you can put it anywhere you want as long as you have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can put Eclipse anywhere, the /Applications folder, or your home ~/ folder.  If you want to keep multiple version of Eclipse, after you installation, you can even rename folder name.